# Check how many times a number appears within another without strings or lists (Python)

Tags: python

I need to find how many times a number appears within another, for example, if I need to find how many times 22 appears of 2228, I need my output to be 1, or if I want to find 12345 in 1234 it must be 0. I can't use either lists or strings, only if and while.

This is my code so far:

```
def contarApariciones (numA, numB):
count = 0
while numB != 0:
    digA = numA % 10
    digB = numB % 10
    position = 1
    searchedN = 0
    while searchedN != numA:
        if digB == digA:
            cuenta +=1
            searchedN = digA + position
            posicion *= 10
            numB // 10
            return count
        else: numB // 10

print (contarApariciones(22,2228))
#output 1
print (contarApariciones(12345,1234))
#output 0
print (contarApariciones(808,80808808))
#output 2
print (contarApariciones(1,10111010))
#output 5
print (contarApariciones(0,0))
```

Comment: I would say that 22 appears in 2228 a total of two times. Do you need to count existence, or literally the exact number of times?

Comment: Yeah I also think it should be two times but I'm asked to get 1 as output. I will update all the scenarios with the outputs I need so maybe you can understand better.

Comment: Cool, that would help. I'd also encourage you to add some comments. At one point, you are doing 1 * position, which is always equal to position. Write some print statements. Just get one example working - then move to the next.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how to get how many times a given number appears inside another, but without using strings or lists, only math.

Comment: Please fix your test calls and indentation. And I suggest another: `contarApariciones (0, 0)`

Comment: what is wrong with them?

Comment: I think I fixed them. I just copied them here from the document of my teacher, thanks for the correction.

Comment: I would argue 808 appears 3 times in 80808808, not two. So the requirement seems to be to count the number of non-overlapping occurrences?

Comment: yes, they can't overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def contarApariciones(numA, numB):
    if numA == 0 == numB:
        return 1
    count = 0
    mod = 10
    while mod <= numA:
        mod *= 10
    while numB:
        if numB % mod == numA:
            count += 1
            numB //= mod
        else:
            numB //= 10
    return count
```

For example for `22` and `2228`, this first computes `mod = 100` to always give us the last two digits of `numB`. Then:

1. `2228 % 100` is `28`. Doesn't match, so drop the `8` and continue with `222`.
2. `222 % 100` is `22`. Matches, so drop the `22` and continue with `2`.
3. `2 % 100` is `2`. Doesn't match, so drop the `2` and continue with `0`.
4. Actually, don't continue, at `0` we stop.

Passes all your tests as well as these:

```
for a in range(1000):
    for b in range(10000):
        expect = str(b).count(str(a))
        result = contarApariciones(a, b)
        assert result == expect
```

Comment: It does work, thanks a lot! I was braking my head trying to evaluate one by one and adding each number but couldn't figure out how. If it isn't too much asking, could you explain me while mod <= numA:
        mod *= 10 ?

Comment: @SAMG23 Well for example if `numA` is `3141`, that has four digits. So you always want to look at the last *four* digits of `numB`. Which is what `numB % 10000` does. So I compute `mod` so that it's the smallest power of 10 larger than `numA`.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought about doing something like that but didn't know how so I got stuck analyzing each number one by one. You saved my life. Thanks a lot!